# What are the 'noisy factors' leading to overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, overfitting, books

Consider the following excerpt from section **5.5 Regularization** (p. 13) of this chapter [Logistic Regression](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/5.pdf).

> There is a problem with learning weights that make the model perfectly match the training data.  If a feature is perfectly predictive of the outcome because it happens to only occur in one class, it will be assigned a very high weight.  The weights for features will attempt to perfectly fit details of the training set, in fact too perfectly, *modeling ***noisy factors*** that just accidentally correlate with the class*. This problem is called overfitting.

What are the 'noisy factors' here? Does it refer to the features that are irrelevant to the class label?

Or does it mean the noise/errors in the values taken by features that accidentally correlate with the class label?

Answer (score 1):

## Please note:

- I am only referring the decision boundary to be a line for simplicity, more often than not it is a hyperplane which is difficult to visualize and spans over `n` dimensions where n is the dimensionality of your feature space.
- The explanation is toned in a more general way for emphasizing explainability.

## Answer

> What are the 'noisy factors' here? Does it refers to the features that are irrelevant to the class label?

- Not Necessarily.

> Or does it mean the noise/errors in the values taken by features that accidentally correlate with the class label?

- I'm not quite sure I understand.

## However

`Noisy factors` as the literature puts it are outliers in a finite data class. Imagine a dataset where we are asked to calculate the average of a set of numbers. Lets say the numbers are the set *S = {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1000}*. The mean value in the case mentioned is 2 if it wasn't for the `1000` at the end.

- 1000 could be an outlier when you are trying to approximate the mean of the set with some algorithm. The algorithm is more likely to encounter a 2 in the unseen test set than the 1000 it encountered once in a training set.
- When an algorithm like Linear Regressions "learns" something it is actually learning the weights and intercepts which modify the position of the line in the decision space.
- The modifications are Translation(Additive operations) and Rotation(Multiplicative operations) to the said line. It is commonly referred to as the "weights" and "biases" respectively in case of a simple line Y = mx + c where m is the `slope` and c is the `intercept`.
- The idea behind noise in the above text is that this:
  When an algorithm is trying to "learn" these weights you would want it to ignore the outliers - "Generalize" but you also want it to not ignore the feature data completely and introduce randomness - "Specialization".
- How well the line is placed in your feature space is what determines your `Classification Effectiveness`.
- In an ideal world you would want your decision boundary to ignore such outliers which are called `noise` in the above literature.

## Pictures (because everyone likes them)

- In the picture below the left image is what a good decision boundary is and the right image is what an overfitted Decision boundary is.
- In the left-image case you are trading misclassifications at the cost of better generalizability(Consider that more likely you are going to see an x in the 2nd quadrant and the o was maybe an outlier). You do not fit your training set completely with a 100% accuracy.
  [image: Normal Decision boundary vs Overfitted Decision Boundary]

## TL;DR

You want the model to learn that the x(s) are on the right and the o(s) are on the left but not so specifically as to which x was where. The x in the 4th quadrant and the o in the second quadrant are `noisy factors`.